An error occurred when I tried to package vue
An error occurred when I tried to package my vue project
the error code is "
PS E:\Important(E)\zhiranbangbang-front\zhiranbangbang> cnpm run build

zhiranbangbang@0.0.0 build
vite build

vite v5.2.8 building for production...
✓ 516 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 1.56s
error during build:
Error: [vite:css] [postcss] EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
file: E:/Important(E)/zhiranbangbang-front/zhiranbangbang/src/views/Login.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&scoped=09bcde41&lang.scss:undefined:NaN
PS E:\Important(E)\zhiranbangbang-front\zhiranbangbang>
"
I checked to see if main.scss was introduced in main.js and it was exist "import './assets/main.scss'"

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What is inside of your Login.vue file?
